# Numpy setup issues in MatLab: callable error

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Let me start by saying I've reviewed several questions similar to this one and not found helpful solutions.

I am converting matlab code to python. I'm taking a function at a time, swapping out the matlab version for a call to my new python function. I'm getting an error in matlab that I'm not getting when I run the script in Pycharm.

Here's the error printed in MatLab:

```
Error using system_models>h (line 54)
Python Error: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Seeing this I went looking for parentheses in my script but didn't find anything.

I call it in Matlab like so:

```
sys_mod = py.importlib.import_module('system_models');
f = sys_mod.f;
h = sys_mod.h;
```

One note that may or may not be relevant: I cannot import modules using the py._italic_module_name_italic_ syntax that matlab recommends. May be a Path issue there that might be a factor in this error.

Here's the python code around that area from system_models.h:

```
    from numpy import sin, cos

    g = 9.806
    # Todo troubleshoot why all zeros works best. Check system models
    Ls = 0  # 0.2 distance from shoulder joint center to upper arm device
    L3 = 0  # 0.35 distance between trunk joint center and shoulder joint center
    Lu = 0.000  # from upper arm device to last joint axis

44    h0 = x[4] * sin(x[6]) + x[1] * cos(x[6]) * cos(x[3])
45    h1a = x[4] * cos(x[6])
46    h1b = x[1] * sin(x[6]) * cos(x[3])
47    h2 = x[7] - x[1] * -sin(x[3])
48    h3 = cos(x[9]) * h0 + sin(x[9]) * h2
49    h4 = x[10] - h1a + h1b
50    h5 = x[13] - sin(x[9]) * h0 + cos(x[9]) * h2
51    h6 = sin(x[12]) * h3 + cos(x[12]) * h4
52    h7 = L3 * h0 + Ls * (h1a - h1b)
53    h8 = x[8] - x[2] * -sin(x[3]) + x[1] * x[4] * cos(x[3])
54
55    h9 = Ls * (x[7] * h0 - x[5] * cos(x[6]) + sin(x[6]) * (x[2] * cos(x[3]) + x[1] * x[4] * -sin(x[3]))) - L3 * (
                cos(x[6]) * (x[2] * cos(x[3]) + x[1] * x[4] * -sin(x[3])) + x[7] * (h1a - h1b) + x[5] * sin(
            x[6])) + g * -sin(x[3]) - L3 * h2 * (h1a - h1b) + Ls * h2 * h0
56
57    h10 = sin(x[9]) * h9 - cos(x[9]) * (h7 * (h1a - h1b) - L3 * h8 + Ls * h2 ** 2 + g * cos(x[6]) * cos(x[3]))
58    h11 = h7 * h0 + Ls * h8 + L3 * h2 ** 2 + g * sin(x[6]) * cos(x[3])
```

Note that line 54 is blank. I added the empty line on accident but then was even more confused when the error pointer didn't change.

Here is the array I grabbed during debugging to test the code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.04242641, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.78539816, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., ])
```

I'm on windows 10, working from a Python3.4 conda environment. I launched matlab from the conda environment.
If someone finds an `x(#)`, I might just leave work and come back in 2020.

Comment: A copy and paste in a plain `ipython` session runs.

Comment: Yep. It runs in my python environement as well. Just not when I call it from matlab.

Comment: How do you call the script? Where is `system_models>h`? Please see [mre].

Comment: I edited my question to show how I call it from matlab.